# Adding OutPutCache to Control Definition Alters its Class ...?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a web app (CMS) that loads controls dynamically into a holder page. Using .Net version 3.5.

All my controls inherit from a custom base class.

So at runtime I have a bit of code that does something like this:

```
Sarx.cms.BaseControl bctl = (Sarx.cms.BaseControl)LoadControl(sourceOfTheControl);
```

All was fine until I added an outputcache directive to the control definition (in the markup).

No, the above cast fails with an InvalidCastException.

I looked at the Control that is the output of the LoadControl and cast, and the runtime reports it is now of type PartialCachingControl:

```
Control c1 = LoadControl(PageData.PageApplications[i].Source);
c1.GetType()
```

UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "PartialCachingControl" FullName = "System.Web.UI.PartialCachingControl"}

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain and/or suggest a workaround.

Thanks in advance,

5arx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [work-around is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163577.aspx) (no. 1 on the list) - easy when you know how.